# pickle: slow dict deserialization

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

Let's suppose I have a "quite large" dictionary, where keys are objects with heavy `__eq__` function

```
class MyObject():

     def __eq__(self, other):
         return <very heavy function call>

     def __hash__(self):
         return <not so heavy hash calculation>

mydict = {<MyObject>:<Int>}
```

The problem is that when I try to unpickle a pickled object, it requires much time. I believe that it is because pickle does not save the internal hash table, and when restoring it recalculates the dictionary.

I did a simple experiment:

```
import pickle 
import pickletools 
original = { 'a': 0, 'b': [1, 2, 3] } 
pickled = pickle.dumps(original) 
pickletools.dis(pickled)
```

results in:

```
    0: \x80 PROTO      3
    2: }    EMPTY_DICT
    3: q    BINPUT     0
    5: (    MARK
    6: X        BINUNICODE 'a'
   12: q        BINPUT     1
   14: K        BININT1    0
   16: X        BINUNICODE 'b'
   22: q        BINPUT     2
   24: ]        EMPTY_LIST
   25: q        BINPUT     3
   27: (        MARK
   28: K            BININT1    1
   30: K            BININT1    2
   32: K            BININT1    3
   34: e            APPENDS    (MARK at 27)
   35: u        SETITEMS   (MARK at 5)
   36: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 2
```

There are no signs of a hashtree. It means that `Pickle Machine` has to recalculate hashtree after deserialization. But it is really dummy? Why pickle does not save the internal state of a dictionary and how one can struggle with it?

Comment: The pickle formats are standardized across Python implementations—they can’t store (only) information sufficient for the implementation of `dict` in one *version* of one interpreter.

Comment: Do you need to save it as a pickle? It seems more efficient if you can just save it as json.

Comment: @Gust, It doesn't work for me, because after load I need a python `dict`. if I will use `json` the building of python `dict` afterload will require the same time. If so, I need a way to initialize python `dict` with pre-calculated hashes.

Comment: If it's actually calling `__eq__` lots of times during load, it'll also call `__eq__` lots of times during use and the rest of the program will be very slow as well. Lots of calls to `__eq__` during unpickling are a sign that `__hash__` has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

- The `__eq__` method is only called on insertion into a `dict` when there's a hash collision (the `__hash__` method for different objects returns the same answer); if this is happening often enough to be a noticeable slow-down, it'll also massively slow down all other operations — in the extreme, if the `__hash__` method always returns the same answer regardless of the value of the object, the `__eq__` method will be called ½n² times just for the unpickle.

  If this is happening, you need to improve your `__hash__` method so that it returns better answers (with fewer duplicates for different values of your object). You can check by manually collecting the results of the `__hash__` method on a representative sample of your objects and making sure that they're mostly different.
- If the above doesn't resolve the issue, I would suggest to profile the code to confirm where the bottleneck is; then you can see if you can speed up the function that's the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

The `Pickle Machine` is implemented across various Python Objects, and certain objects may not like a hash implementation, and may brake.

If, all your going do is save Json Objects, use the `json` object as its will be efficient.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, because after load I need a python dict. if I will use json the building of python `dict` will have the same time.

Answer (score 0):

## Use pickled objects as dictionary keys instead.

By using the pickled object as the key, we can circumvent the `MyObject.__hash__` and `MyObject.__eq__` methods altogether and potentially speed up the unpickling process.

Once you have the unpickled dictionary, you can slowly change the pickeled keys to actual MyObject instances as you need them.

## p1.py

Create a dictionary where keys are of type MyObject then pickle them to a file.
Create a dictionary where the keys are pickled MyObject bytes.
Compare the times required to unpickle each dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pickle
import pickletools
from pprint import pprint
import random
import string
import time

random.seed(19891225)


class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        exit(1)
        return self.value == other.value

    def __hash__(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        return hash(tuple(self.value))


def key_value():
    value_len = random.randint(0,len(string.ascii_letters))
    value = random.sample(string.ascii_letters, value_len)
    return (MyObject(value), value_len)

def object_key_dict(size=10):
    return dict([key_value() for i in range(0, size)])

def pickle_key_dict(d):
    return {pickle.dumps(k):v for k, v in d.items()}

def pickle_unpickle(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, "wb") as pout:
        pickle.dump(obj, pout)

    print(f"Unpickle Start: {time.strftime('%H:%M:%s')}")
    with open(filename, "rb") as pin:
        newobj = pickle.load(pin)
    print(f"Unpickle complete: {time.strftime('%H:%M:%s')}")
    print("-"*20)

    return newobj


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = object_key_dict(size=10)

    print("Use MyObject instances as dictionary keys")
    unpickled_d = pickle_unpickle(d, 'doc.p')

    print("\nUse pickled ojbects as dicitonary keys")
    pd = pickle_key_dict(unpickled_d)
    upd = pickle_unpickle(pd, 'docp.p')
```

## Output

```
Use MyObject instances as dictionary keys
Unpickle Start: 09:25:1589808319
Unpickle complete: 09:26:1589808419
--------------------

Use pickled ojbects as dicitonary keys
Unpickle Start: 09:26:1589808419
Unpickle complete: 09:26:1589808419
--------------------
```

Comment: The __eq__ method will be called when there's a hash collision; you can test this by returning a constant from __hash__.

Comment: That may be the case;however if the pickled object is used as the key, it will still circumvent the objects hash and eq methods. Additionally, I tried the code using duplicate objects and the eq method still wasn’t called during the unpickling process. Which is the crux of this question.

Comment: I just double-checked, and `__eq__` is in fact called during unpickling; this is for objects which are different (not equal, `__eq__` returns `False`), but have the same hash value, using `def __hash__(self): return 1` to make sure of that. (If the objects are equal, your `object_key_dict` function will return a dict with only one element.)

Comment: I’m not arguing that __eq__ would never be called. But aren’t you forcing a worse-case scenario by building a hash function that always returns 1? You and I absolutely agree. It’s the hash function that is causing the issue with this question. Not much more we can do without more information related to the business rules, implementation and the amount of data.

Comment: Yeah, I'm forcing a worst-case scenario in order to verify that `__eq__` can in fact be called during unpickling. However, if the `__eq__` method is a substantial slow-down in unpickling, I suspect the real scenario is not very far from this...

Comment: I mean, it's not difficult to accidentally write a `__hash__` method that returns only a few different values, or just one; for instance, hashing just the keys of a dict rather than the values.